# How to pause Eclipse on any exception?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, exception

I found the "Add Java Exception Breakpoint" menu item but it only seems to work on the exact exception type that I select. So if I ask it to break on `Exception`, it does not break in case of a `NumberFormatException`. How do I make it break for all exceptions?

My activity is exiting for no apparent reason with no LogCat output, so it would be nice to find out about any exceptions that are occurring, whether caught or uncaught and whether in my code or just in Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. create an exception breakpoint for `java.lang.Throwable` (which is the most specific superclass of all exceptions - unlike `Exception`, it also matches instances of `Error`)
2. right-click it, choose properties, and check "subclasses of this exception"

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that already, and did you read my question? `NumberFormatException` is a subclass of `Exception`. A breakpoint for `NumberFormatException` works but one for `Exception` does not break on the former, at least not for me.

Comment: Did you read (and do) step 2 before forming that opinion? If "subclasses of this exception" is checked, subclasses of the exception are considered, too ...

Comment: Uh-oh, I didn't read part 2, and that makes me a hypocrite :( - confirmed, in the "Breakpoints" panel, one must right-click the `Exception` or `Throwable` breakpoint and edit `Breakpoint Properties`. Unfortunately, it turns out there is an exception (ClassNotFoundException) for every single class that gets loaded, which makes me wonder if there is a way to filter those out.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this using the pattern matching it specifies in the window. Specifically, `*` will match any string (including the empty string) so `*Exception*` will match all strings which contain the substring `Exception` in them, including the string `Exception` itself and strings which have `Exception` at the very beginning or very end.

Comment: That's a just filter string I'm afraid. You can't add a breakpoint for `*Exception*`.

Comment: This answer is wrong as you have to select exactly one type of exception class. As written above this string is just for filtering the dialog contents.

Comment: Woops, you can tell it was the end of the day when I posted this. Don't think this is adding to the discussion at all...